# Empty Line Before Start Of SMS using GSM

Tags: vb.net, sms, gsm

I have developed an SMS app in winform using vb.net. I can send SMS to any valid number. The problem I am facing right now is that when I send a message to a number it is received with an empty line before the SMS starting line and the text appears in the next line. Any solution regarding this problem? Thanks

Comment: Add the chr(13) & chr(10) to the beginning of your message string?

Comment: chr(10) was actually the reason of this problem i.e vbLf which means "go to next line". Replaced it with chr(13) i.e. vbCr which means " return to line beginning" and the issue is resolved. Thanks for your kind suggestion. @DavidWilson